# Writing a JEST unit test with React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am new to unit testing would really appreciate help.
Below is the component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Textfit} from 'react-textfit'; //This will fit the text how big or small it is.

class DisplayPanel extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        return (
            <Textfit className="calculator-display">{this.props.value}</Textfit>
        );
    }
}

DisplayPanel.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
};

export default DisplayPanel
```

I want to write a test scenario in regards to the

```
<Textfit className="calculator-display">{this.props.value}</Textfit>
```

that checks for the components has value setup.

How can I do this with jest and enzyme?

I have tried the code for tests as below :

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import DisplayPanel from "../components/DisplayPanel";
import { Textfit } from "react-textfit";

describe("Display Panel", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => (wrapper = shallow(<DisplayPanel/>)));

  it("should render correctly", () => expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot());

  it("should render a Textfit component", () => {
    expect(wrapper.containsMatchingElement(<Textfit />)).toEqual(true);
  });

   //what should come here
   it("renders the value", () => {
    //expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('0');
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't test the framework, test your logic

If you pass a value as a prop it will have that as a prop. There is no need to test this. You're essentially writing a test for react itself. You can however see what value exists inside your component.

## Enzyme

This is made easy with [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) (from airbnb) . Check out the text method they have [here](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/text.html)

## Example (from docs)

```
const wrapper = mount(<div><b>important</b></div>);
expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('important');
```

You can test `this.props.value` easily with this.

## Edit 1

You should be able to find the shallow rendered element via the [find](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) function in Enzyme

```
import Foo from '../components/Foo';

const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

Perhaps it can be combined with the `text` function. I don't have an on hand example/sandbox right now.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, really appreciate your guidance. Can you help me a bit more, I have updated the question to have my test case, I dont know what to put in the last one.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: @MollyChristian you will not be able to check the value in this test because you're doing a shallow render. 
Check your snapshot and you'll see the the component `<Textfit />`. This means that you can never check the value. to make the full tree render you'll need to mount `wrapper = mount(<DisplayPanel/>))`

Comment: Thankyou but I have tried with mount aswell and when running the tests it takes a lot of time.I have seen it for running more than 200 seconds and I stopped the test. Am using the textfit library, not sure why is it taking so much of time.Shallow works ok, but not with mount.